# RadioButtonList null value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `RadioButtonList` and a submit button on a web form. When I click the submit button with a null `RadioButtonList` value, i.e. without selected anything from the `RadioButtonList`, I get an exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of object.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //for qstn 1
    con.Open();

    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == null)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand("update TEST1 set Your_Answer=NULL where Question='1'", con);
        sqlcmd1.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    else
    {
        string rb1 = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update TEST1 set Your_Answer='" + rb1 + "' where Question='1'", con);
        cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if any of element is selected as SelectedValue wont be null event none of element is selected. As stateted on MSDN about [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  *"A ListItem that represents the lowest indexed item selected from the list control. The default is null"* and if SelectedItem is null you can not access Text property and will get exception.

```
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand("update TEST1 set Your_Answer=NULL where Question='1'", con);
        sqlcmd1.ExecuteScalar();

    }
    else
    {
        string rb1 = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update TEST1 set Your_Answer='" + rb1 + "' where Question='1'", con);
        cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
    }}
```

OR

You can use SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue in the condtion as stated by Grant Winney.

```
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null)
```